# How comes I get "undefined method `model_name' for {:model=>#<RealQuoteLine ... " when the name is right there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model, query-string

Can somebody PLEASE explain this to me? I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Quotations#work undefined method `model_name' for {:model=>#<RealQuoteLine id: 303, quote_concept: "Exportación Aerea CDMX", quantity: 1, unit_price: 0.134e3, real_segment_id: 194, created_at: "2023-08-10 19:56:48.617556000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-08-10 19:56:48.617556000
```

The error reported is in this line:

```
<%= form.fields_for(model: rql) do |line_form| %>
```

The part that baffles me is: `undefined method model_name' for {:model=>#<RealQuoteLine`

Is not the model name present there? I'm sure there is an explanation and something I am not having in mind, that will help me a lot.

The Quotations#work action method is :

```rb
<div>
  <h3>Captura de Cotización</h3>
</div>
<table class="show-table" >
  <tr>
    <td class="fw-light">Cotización:</td>
    <td><%= @quotation.id %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fw-light">Requerimiento:</td>
    <td><%= @quotation.request.description %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fw-light">Cliente:</td>
    <td><%= @quotation.request.client.name %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="container">
  <% @quotation.real_service_group.tap do |rsg| %>
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col">
        <span>Servicio:</span>
        <span><%= rsg.title %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% rsg.real_segments.each do |rs| %>
    <div class="row mt-8">
      <div class="col">
        <span>Segmento:</span>
        <span><%= rs.title %></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>Moneda:</span>
        <span><%= rs.currency %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col">
        <span>Concepto</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>Cantidad</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>Precio Unitario</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>importe</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <% subtotal_segmento = 0 %>

    <%= form_with model: rs, method: :put do |form| %>
      <% rs.real_quote_lines.each do |rql| %>
        <div data-controller="linea-cotizacion">
          <div class="row mt-4">
            <%= form.fields_for(model: rql) do |line_form| %>
              <div class="col">
                <%= line_form.text_field :quote_concept, value: rql.quote_concept, readonly: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <%= line_form.text_field :quantity, class: "linea-cantidad", data: { target: 'linea-cotizacion.quantity' } %>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                  <%= line_form.number_field :unit_price, 
                                            data: { 
                                              target: 'linea-cotizacion.unitPrice',
                                              action: 'focusout->linea-cotizacion#updateImporte'
                                            } %>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <%= content_tag(:span, '', id: 'importe', class: "fw-bold") %>
              </div>
              <%= line_form.hidden_field :id %>
              <%= line_form.hidden_field :real_segment_id %>
            <% end %> <%# end fields_for %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %> <%# end each real_quote_lines (rql) %>
        <p style="background-color: darkgray;">
          <span class="text-end">Subtotal</span>
          <span id="subtotal-segmento"><%= number_to_currency(subtotal_segmento) %></span>
        </p>
        <div class="row mt-4">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span>
              <%= form.submit "Guardar Segmento", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %> <%# end  form_with%>
    <% end %> <%# end real_segments.each (rs) %>
  <% end %> <%# end real_service_group.tap (rsg) %>
</div>
```

The involved models and params:

```rb
class RealSegment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :real_service_group
  has_many :real_quote_lines, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :real_quote_lines, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```
class RealQuoteLine < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :real_segment, class_name: "RealSegment"
end
```

```
def real_segment_params
    params.require(:real_segment).permit(:id, :title, :currency, :iva, :retention, :real_service_group_id, real_quote_lines_attributes: %i[id real_segment_id quote_concept quantity unit_price])
  end
```

And this is what I can get from the error console:

```rb
>> rql
=> #<RealQuoteLine id: 303, quote_concept: "Exportación Aerea CDMX", quantity: 1, unit_price: 0.134e3, real_segment_id: 194, created_at: "2023-08-10 19:56:48.617556000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-08-10 19:56:48.617556000 +0000">
>> rql.class
=> RealQuoteLine (call 'RealQuoteLine.connection' to establish a connection)
>>
```

I'm trying to update the values on the `real_quote_lines` table row, I have tried several configurations and still not able to advance... I suspect it has to do with the fact that `rql` is an argument passed to the block with: `<% rs.real_quote_lines.each do |rql| %>` but then waht is the right wat to do it?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I updated the post to show the method, I hope it is enough...txs

Comment: Isn’t model_name a class method? You seem to be passing a collection, not a model or a single instance.

Comment: Got it. This line `form.fields_for(model: rql) do |line_form|` is incorrect. [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) is anticipating the model but you are passing a `Hash`. Trying changing this to `form.fields_for(rql) do |line_form|` or review the docs linked here for more details on how to implement this functionality

Answer (score 2):

You're actually just making it difficult for yourself here by using the `fields_for` method incorrectly.

You just need to pass the name of the association that you're creating inputs for:

```
<%= form_with model: rs, method: :put do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :real_quote_lines do |line_form| %>
    <div data-controller="linea-cotizacion">
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <%= line_form.text_field :quote_concept, readonly: true %>
        </div>
         # ...
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Fields for will iterate across the collection and create inputs for each record including the hidden input for the id when updating existing records. You do not need or want a input for the parent id.

The usage of the method is detailed [in the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) and the [API documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: On a side note remember accessibility - provide labels and use actual interactive elements such as buttons instead of slapping behavior onto a span.

Comment: @engineersmnky I just removed the manual assignment. I'm not sure the issue is so much that it's an implicit hash as that `fields_for` doesn't have the same signature as `form_with`. It expects either a name for the inputs and an optional collection or a model that supports the ActiveModel::Naming API.

Comment: Just noticed something weird: When using <%= form.fields_for :real_quote_lines do |line_form| %> The quote_lines for THE FIRST segment are repeated??? Why? If I use <%= form.fields_for rql do |line_form| %> the lines won't repeat but the quantity won't update...

Comment: Finally I got the desired result using: <%= form.fields_for :real_quote_lines, rql do |line_form| %> just as the documentation says...

Comment: That should not be necessary. You're doing something wonky - but I can't really see what you're coding at the moment